# Is there a similar notion of cycle type commonly in use for finite partitions, where instead of cycle sizes one counts the block sizes?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, equivalence-relations, set-partition

I want to apply statistical analysis, in particular work with various measurements on the absolute frequency of blocks of a fixed cardinality in a finite partition. I've found a convoluted and ugly looking way to describe this using degree sequences of graphs, though I'm wondering if there is some nicer standard definition for extracting this information like one does with the cycle type of a permutation. As I'd rather not be making up a bunch of definitions/notation if I don't have to.

To be precise I'm trying to get a multiset or a sequence of the cardinalities of each set in a finite partition. However if possible I don't want to make up my own notation. E.g. using the partition:

$$\{\{a,b,c\},\{2,8,9\},\{\pi,\tau\},\{\alpha,\beta\},\{\delta,\gamma\},\{i\},\{j\}\}$$

This would correspond with the multiset $\{3,3,2,2,2,1,1\}$ or the sequence $(3,3,2,2,2,1,1)$.

Comment: One usually uses the same notation as the one used to write cycyle structure for permutations. $1^22^33^2$ for your example.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks, to write that formally would I say then the "partition type" or "quotient set type" or something else? Is there an analogous cycle index I would reference for partitions?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by ćycle index. As for writing "formally": just explain what the notation means in words — you are communicating with humans.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Like in combinatorics when you construct a multivariable polynomial for each permutation in a group. And then that polynomial is useful for calculating stuff. Is what I meant with cycle index. Anyway I appreciate your response.

Comment: But that is attached to a group of permutations. What do you want a "group of partitions"to be?

Comment: Well, use the cycle index of that group.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Nvm I'm being dumb. Anyway thx again for the notation advice.